# joomla virtuemart change list product view

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

The site I am working on is [here](http://www.jakovsistem.com/webshop/laptop-racunari) , using Joomla v1.5.23 and Viruemart 1.1.9

I need to add new way of listing products, so that the customer can change views.  I don't know where to start. I googled a lot but it is still very confusing to me.

Do I have to make new modul, theme or templates or there is some magic button in admin panel where I can change the view?  Can you give me some links to tutorials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way a product is displayed in VM is with the "flypages" (that's what you want to google for).  The installation provides a few samples (they're not particularly great), though they give you an idea how to modify the appearance of the page. You can specify which flypage to use in a link, but I think VM natively chooses one based on the category in which the product exists (A product can be in mulitple categories too).

Comment: Thank you. I have found those pages